# how to get if user likes a post or not with Facebook Graph API in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Facebook Graph API let us use this to get all likes of a "post"

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"post_id/likes" andDelegate:self];
```

(post id type maybe status, photo, or link etc)

post id ,ex: 183039808383895_363838080355846

we also can use this to get all likes of a "comment"

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"comment_id/likes" andDelegate:self];
```

comment id ex: 183039808383895_363838080355846_3047357

if we use this, we can get if user likes this "comment"

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"comment_id?fields=user_likes" andDelegate:self];
```

the result is

```
{
"user_likes": false,
"id": "183039808383895_363838080355846_3047357",
"created_time": "2012-07-11T14:01:42+0000"
}
```

but how do I get if user likes a "post" or not
if I use this

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"post_id?fields=user_likes" andDelegate:self];
```

but it doesn't work, I got a error.